# Add rank to histogram

Tags: r

I have  a dataset like these which show the height of 10 European countries for men.

---

| Country | Height |
| --- | --- |
| UK | 176 |
| Ireland | 175 |
| Cyprus | 174 |
| Belgium | 179 |
| Netherlands | 180 |
| Sweden | 178 |
| Norway | 181 |
| Spain | 173 |
| Italy | 171 |
| France | 177 |

---

I would like to create a histogram which shows the country name in a alphabetic order and shows above the bar the rank of the country.

I started already but got not the solution

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Country, y=Height)) + geom_line(aes())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. Here is the data. Please provide the sample dataframe in your future questions.

```
df <- data.frame(Country = c(
"UK", 
"Ireland", 
"Cyprus", 
"Belgium", 
"Netherlands", 
"Sweden", 
"Norway", 
"Spain", 
"Italy", 
"France"),
Height = c(176, 175, 174, 179, 180, 
178, 181, 173, 171, 177))
```

Second. I would propose to prepare the data first. Let us add a special column for ranks and transform the Country column to ordered factor:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(rnk = rank(Height), Country = factor(Country, ordered = T))
```

Third. Let us plot:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(y = rnk, x = Country)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
geom_text(aes(label=rnk), vjust = -1)
```

In this plot we crate the following layers: the barplot with rank as y coord and Country name as x coord and text values of ranks. You can set exact values of Heights instead of ranks inside `aes(y = Height,...`

Finally you get this:

[image]

Or this with replaced aesthetics:

[image]